# Access to registry key that match regexp via code

Tags: c#, regex, postgresql, registry, registrykey

I'd like to access to Postgresql registry keys (to get postgresql installation path).
I know that they are located in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\postgresql-x64-9.5
```

For a 64 bit computer with 9.5 postgresql version.

Now I'd like to access to this key from any PC (32/64 bit) with different postgre installed version (9.0, 9.1...).
The path could be something like

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\postgresql-x[64|86]-9.[0-5]
```

The standard way to access to registry key in C# is the following

```
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\postgresql-x64-9.5");
```

But it works only with absolute registry key path.

Is there a way to use regular expressions to get registry subkeys?

Answer (score 0):

In your regex:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\postgresql-x[64|86]-9.[0-5]
```

`[64|86]` means: Match a `6`, a `4`, a `|`, an `8` or a `6`.

Change it to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\postgresql-x(64|86)-9.[0-5]
```

To get `64` or `86` bit version.

---

To enumerate all the possibilities, you can use this code:

```
RegistryKey key = null;

foreach (var version in new List<string>{"64" , "86"})
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(String.Format("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\postgresql-x{0}-9.{1}", version, i));
        if(key != null)
            break;
    }
    if (key != null)
        break;
}
// Do something with key
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it is not the point of my question. I am not able to use a regexp with the OpenSubKey method, because that method need only a string with the absolute path